# Why are receivers pass by value in Go?

Tags: go

Seems like you'd ALWAYS want this:

```
func (self *Widget) Do() {
}
```

instead of this

```
func (self Widget) Do() {
}
```

If so, then the way to get the former semantics *OUGHT* to be by using the latter syntax. i.e. receivers ought to be pass by reference.

Answer (score 31):

It is because [everything in Go is pass by value](http://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value). This makes it consistent with other C family languages, and means that you never need to remember whether the situation you're looking at is pass by value or not.

From that link:

> As in all languages in the C family, everything in Go is passed by value. That is, a function always gets a copy of the thing being passed, as if there were an assignment statement assigning the value to the parameter. For instance, passing an int value to a function makes a copy of the int, and passing a pointer value makes a copy of the pointer, but not the data it points to. (See the next section for a discussion of how this affects method receivers.)

Then later:

> ```
>   func (s *MyStruct) pointerMethod() { } // method on pointer
>   func (s MyStruct)  valueMethod()   { } // method on value
> ```
>
> For programmers unaccustomed to pointers, the distinction between these two examples can be confusing, but the situation is actually very simple. When defining a method on a type, the receiver (`s` in the above examples) behaves exactly as if it were an argument to the method. Whether to define the receiver as a value or as a pointer is the same question, then, as whether a function argument should be a value or a pointer. There are several considerations.
>
> First, and most important, does the method need to modify the receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer. (Slices and maps act as references, so their story is a little more subtle, but for instance to change the length of a slice in a method the receiver must still be a pointer.) In the examples above, if pointerMethod modifies the fields of `s`, the caller will see those changes, but valueMethod is called with a copy of the caller's argument (that's the definition of passing a value), so changes it makes will be invisible to the caller.
>
> By the way, pointer receivers are identical to the situation in Java, although in Java the pointers are hidden under the covers; it's Go's value receivers that are unusual.
>
> Second is the consideration of efficiency. If the receiver is large, a big struct for instance, it will be much cheaper to use a pointer receiver.
>
> Next is consistency. If some of the methods of the type must have pointer receivers, the rest should too, so the method set is consistent regardless of how the type is used. See the section on method sets for details.
>
> For types such as basic types, slices, and small structs, a value receiver is very cheap so unless the semantics of the method requires a pointer, a value receiver is efficient and clear.

Comment: Everything in the second quote suggests to me that in a good design, almost every receiver should be a pointer. The only case that it mentions where you might consider using non-pointer is when the value is small. Generalizing for the sake of the small value case at the cost of discouraging good design does not seem like a good choice.

Comment: The choice taken is a) natural to those with `C` background (and `Go` is pretty lower-level than, say, `Java` or `.NET`, and b) offers more freedom to the programmer. Expanding on the last point, `Go` allows you to access a value through a pointer to it by just applying the dot operator (`.`) to the name of that pointer, without using any dereferencing operator (`*`), so if you think it's a problem for you, just always use pointer receivers as the code inside your methods will be no harder to write (no over-usage of `*`s and `->`s as in `C` or `C++`).

Comment: @kostix Not having to do -> is yet another reason that non-pointer receivers makes little sense. Go is much more comparable to Java than it is to C: garbage collection, interfaces, safety, concurrency.

Comment: Just one thing: *"As in all languages in the C family,..."* ->C++ is not, since there is also 'reference' in C++. Anyways it's true that everything in Go is "pass by value", as well as C and some other modern OOP languages such as JAVA, C#, Python, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you *don't* want to pass by reference though. The semantics of

```
func (self Widget) Get() Value {
}
```

Can be useful if for instance you have a small immutable object. The caller can know for certain that this method doesn't modify it's reciever. They *can't* know this if the reciever is a pointer without reading the code first.

To expand on that for instance

```
// accessor for things Config
func (self Thing) GetConfig() *Config {
}
```

Just by looking at this method I can know GetConfig is always going to return the same Config. I can modify that config but I can't modify the pointer to Config inside Thing. It's pretty close to a const pointer inside of Thing.

Comment: That's why Go should have const :P

Comment: You don't know that GetConfig returns the same config; that's only if it does not attempt to access global state E.g. the system's random number generator.

Comment: Copying should not be used as a defense against modification. It works, but it has significant (hidden) performance cost.

Answer (score 2):

> Seems like you'd ALWAYS want this:

No. The value receiver is more general. It can be used in all the places that a pointer receiver can; but a pointer receiver cannot be used in all the places that a value receiver can -- for example, if you have an rvalue expression of the type `Widget`; you can call value-receiver methods on it, but not pointer-receiver methods.

Comment: That seems like an anti-pattern. Seems like your expressions should be of type *Widget. Otherwise, you're probably going to end up unwittingly copying lots of data around.

Comment: You can't use a value receiver when you want to modify the object itself, right? So you can't *always* use a value receiver.

Comment: @korylprince: That's not what I meant by "can be used". What I meant was, given you have a method with a value receiver and a method with a pointer receiver, there are some expression contexts where you cannot (as in it does not compile) use the method with pointer receiver, but where you can use the method with value receiver. Of course, certain things cannot be done with methods with value receivers. But that's not what the question is about. The question asks about a hypothetical value-receiver method, and asks whether it should always be made pointer-receiver.