# How to have many structs inside a struct?

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a struct of called class like this.

```
type ClassDetails struct {
ClassNumber int `json:"classNumber"`
Names []string `json:names`}
```

I have manually created something like this.

```
type Subject struct {
Math ClassDetails `json:"math"`
Science ClassDetails `json:"science"`}
```

I want to do this on the fly. Add more ClassDetails to the Subject as I get information, but I cannot use an array of type class. 
 How can this be done? And I also need to add the names of the classes as the json tag.
My resultant struct should hold values like this.

```
{
    "classes": {
        "school": "MayorWestHigh",
        "math": [{
                "classNumber": "1",
                "names": ["aaron", "baron", "cathy"]
            },
            {
                "classNumber": "2",
                "names": ["aaron", "baron", "cathy"]
            }
        ],
        "science": [{
            "classNumber": "1",
            "names": ["ted", "baron", "isiah"]
        }],
        "geography": [{
            "classNumber": "1",
            "names": ["peter", "glen", "joe"]
        }]

    }
}
```

Comment: Use pointers.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining golang struct function using pointer or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382073/defining-golang-struct-function-using-pointer-or-not)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch using pointers doesn't make any difference to the question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of statically defining each subject, how about simply using a map from subject name => array of class details ?

One way you can get very close to the JSON you want by using a map like I described above, and by embedding the map into a struct as follows:

```
type ClassDetails struct {
    ClassNumber int      `json:"classNumber"`
    Names       []string `json:names`
}

type Subjects map[string][]ClassDetails

type Classes struct {
    School string `json:"school"`
    Subjects
}
```

An instance of the `Classes` struct above would fill in the following part of your desired JSON:

```
{
  "classes": {
    ... the Classes instance goes here...
  }
}
```

The remaining outer object can just be constructed as follows:

```
c := Classes{...}
outer := map[string]Classes{"classes": c}
```

A JSON marshal of the `outer` object, with the right data initialized, arrives at almost exactly your JSON above (to match it exactly you'd have to turn the `ClassNumber` into a string type).

Here is a Go Playground link that initializes these structs with the exact data you want and pretty-prints your JSON: https://play.golang.org/p/HFMbHtY2os

EDIT: This still doesn't exactly match the JSON in your question, as it will add a new object in there called "Subjects". The problem is that the object inside of `"classes"` in your JSON mixes types, and Go can't declare dynamic struct fields.

If you really have to use that JSON structure, you'll need to go with the more generic `map[string]interface{}` to allow mixed types at the same level in your object hierarchy. Here's another Go Playground link that has the correct implementation: https://play.golang.org/p/rlYTYGofSI

Comment: You have wrapped the different subjects into classes. I cannot use an array of classes. It should just be a struct with multiple class objects.

Comment: I edited my answer with a new playground link that uses `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: Thanks. I can live with a generic type for now.