# Initialize a nil pointer struct in method

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I have a struct called `Article` which has a field called `Image`. Per default `Image` has value `nil`. As `Image` should be only persisted as `Image.Id` to database I use the `bson.BSONGetter`, `bson.BSONSetter` and `json.Marshaler` interfaces to fake this behavior.

However internally it is possible to use `Image` as an `io.ReadWriteCloser` if I load a file onto this with some other helper.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

type Article struct {
    Name  string
    Image *Image
}

type Image struct {
    Id interface{}

    io.ReadWriteCloser
}

func (i *Image) SetBSON(r bson.Raw) error {
    i = &Image{}

    return r.Marshal(i.Id)
}

func (i *Image) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    return i.Id
}

func (i *Image) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(i.Id)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/WDnaHlQBuU)

The problem with this approach now is that it is not possible to initialize `Image` in `Image.SetBSON` as `Image` is `nil`.

Comment: What is your question? I don't see a single sentence that looks like it could be a question in your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The receiver is **[passed by value](http://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value)**, including the pointer receiver: it is a copy, and changing its value doesn't change the initial pointer receiver on which the method is called.

See "[Why are receivers pass by value in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18435638/6309)".

A function `Setup` returning a new *Foo would work better: [<kbd>play.golang.org</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/doGUAtMXDz)

```
func SetUp() *Foo {
    return &Foo{"Hello World"}
}

func main() {
    var f *Foo
    f = SetUp()
}
```

Output:

```
Foo: <nil>
Foo: &{Bar:Hello World}
```

---

[twotwotwo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2714852/twotwotwo) points to a better convention [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520485/initialize-a-nil-pointer-struct-in-method/25520558?noredirect=1#comment39841449_25520558), which is to make a package function `foo.New()`, as in [`sha512.New()`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha512/#New).
But here, your `Setup()` function might do more than just creating a `*Foo`.

Comment: Or, following the convention of the standard library, `NewFoo() *Foo` (or if the module is named `foo`, just `foo.New()`, like how `crypto/sha512` exports `sha512.New()`).

Comment: @VonC okay I think it is a good idea to show you the big picture maybe my approach makes more sense then.

Comment: @twotwotwo good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @bodokaiser whatever setup is doing in your "big picture", it needs to *return* a `*Foo` (in addition of anything else it does)

Comment: @VonC Really? Maybe you have a better idea for the overall case.

Comment: @bodokaiser no, I don't. My point is simply that you won't be able to modify the pointer receiver directly.

Comment: @VonC Okay maybe you could express the **not possible** a bit more in your answer. I will then move this to the user group :)

Comment: @bodokaiser meaning: `SetBSON()`: `i = &Image{}` will never work, since `i` `*Image` is a *copy* of `Image *Image` you use to call that method.

Answer (score 1):

`bson.Unmarshal` creates a pointer to an `Image` value when it comes across it in the bson data. So once we enter `SetBSON` `i` is already a valid pointer to an `Image` struct. That means that there is no reason for you to allocate the `Image`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type Article struct {
    Name  string
    Image *Image `bson:"image,omitempty"`
}

type Image struct {
    Id          interface{}
    AlsoIgnored string
    io.ReadWriteCloser
}

func (i *Image) SetBSON(r bson.Raw) error {
    err := r.Unmarshal(&i.Id)
    return err

}

func (i Image) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    return i.Id, nil
}

func main() {
    backAndForth(Article{
        Name: "It's all fun and games until someone pokes an eye out",
        Image: &Image{
            Id:          "123",
            AlsoIgnored: "test",
        },
    })

    backAndForth(Article{Name: "No img attached"})
}

func backAndForth(a Article) {
    bsonData, err := bson.Marshal(a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("bson form: '%s'\n", string(bsonData))

    article := &Article{}
    err = bson.Unmarshal(bsonData, article)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("go form  : %#v - %v\n", article, article.Image)

}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/_wb6_8Pe-3

Output is:

```
bson form: 'Tname6It's all fun and games until someone pokes an eye outimage123'
go form  : &main.Article{Name:"It's all fun and games until someone pokes an eye out", Image:(*main.Image)(0x20826c4b0)} - &{123  <nil>}
bson form: 'nameNo img attached'
go form  : &main.Article{Name:"No img attached", Image:(*main.Image)(nil)} - <nil>
```

Comment: Interesting alternative, more detailed than my answer. +1

Comment: @stengaard I do not get the benefit of such a method. I mean isn't the problem that I cannot set a field in BSONSetter on an nil pointer?

Comment: @bodokaiser - yes, you are right. Just updated my answer to actually solve the original problem (though my first solution did sidestep the issue).

Comment: But in my case this leads to a panic because nil has no field `id`.